# How to upload excel or csv file to flask as a Pandas data frame?

Tags: python, pandas, flask

I have been trying to upload a csv/excel file as pandas data frame on a flask application. I am not able to find any method which could help upload the file as a data frame. Below is the code used.

```
from flask import Flask, request, render_template
from werkzeug import secure_filename
import pandas as pd
app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/upload')
def upload():
    return render_template('upload.html')

@app.route('/uploader',methods = ['GET','POST'])
def uploader():
    if request.method == 'POST':
        #f = request.files['file']
        df = pd.read_csv(request.files.get('file'))
        #f.save(secure_filename(f.filename))
        #df = pd.DataFrame(eval(f))
        return print(df.shape)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(debug = True)
```

Answer (score 12):

You didn't provide a template you're using in your code (`upload.html`).
Also `return print(...)` returns `None` and `None` is not a valid response from a Flask view.

Here's a working example:

**upload.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Title</title>
</head>
<body>
<form method=post enctype=multipart/form-data>
    <input type=file name=file>
    <input type=submit value=Upload>
</form>
Shape is: {{ shape }}
</body>
</html>
```

**app.py**

```
from flask import Flask, request, render_template
import pandas as pd

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/upload', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def upload():
    if request.method == 'POST':
        df = pd.read_csv(request.files.get('file'))
        return render_template('upload.html', shape=df.shape)
    return render_template('upload.html')

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(debug=True)
```

**dummy.csv**

```
id,name,surname
1,John,Doe
2,Jane,Doe
```

Result after uploading `dummy.csv`:
[image]

Comment: Hi @kchomski, I have another object like  {{shape}} say {{columns}} which is df.columns, which I want to display after the if loop runs and displays shape , along with the 2nd return but the loop stops at the 1st return after the if condition satisfies. How can I get what I want?